# Primefaces <p:dataTable> roweditlistener is not an valid argument

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I am using Primefaces 3.0.M and it's data table.

I have set it to use in-line edition, but know I need to persist my data after it's been modified, so I figured rowEditListener would do it.

But when I do this it says `rowEditListener` is not a defined in the interface of the component, and I cannot find any doc about this..

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}"
rowEditListener="#{carBean.onEditRow}">
```

Anyone ? is there another solution to call a method after edition mode is done in the in-line editor ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In primefaces 3.0.M3 it should be done using ajax like this

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userController.allUsers}" id="userList">  
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{userController.onEditRow}" />
```

Instead of using the old rowEditListener, and there should be a method taking `RowEditEvent`  as a parameter in your managed bean

```
public void onEditRow(RowEditEvent event) {
    User nutzer = (User) event.getObject();                 

    User user = userFacade.find(nutzer.getId());

    user.setName(nutzer.getName());
    user.setLogin(nutzer.getLogin());

    userFacade.edit(user);
}
```